# averaging an array in a separate method

Tags: java

My original code is:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String str1;
        String str2;
        String str3;
        int    numbersToAverage;

        str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of numbers you would like to average: ");
        numbersToAverage = Integer.parseInt(str1);

        // while statement will provide error message so user cannot enter 0
        while (numbersToAverage < 1) {
            str3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid entry: Please enter one or more numbers to average: ");
            numbersToAverage = Integer.parseInt(str3);
        }

        // array size is set to equal user input
        double[] numbers = new double[numbersToAverage];
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersToAverage; i++) {
            str2       = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number " + (i + 1)
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(str2);

            // the sum equals numbers in the array added together
            sum += numbers[i];
        }

        // Calculates the average of the numbers entered by the user
        double average = sum / numbersToAverage;

        // Prints in a dialogue box to user the average
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average of the numbers you entered is: " + average);
    }
}
```

and I am now having to calculate the average in a separate method and I am having a hard time figuring out how to do that?  So far I have:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class average {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1;
        String str2;
        String str3;
        int numbersToAverage;

        str1 = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of numbers you would like to average: ");
        numbersToAverage = Integer.parseInt(str1);

        // while statement will provide error message so user cannot enter 0
        while (numbersToAverage < 1) {
            str3 = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Invalid entry: Please enter one or more numbers to average: ");
            numbersToAverage = Integer.parseInt(str3);
        }

        // array size is set to equal user input
        double[] numbers = new double[numbersToAverage];

        //double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersToAverage; i++) {
            str2       = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number " + (i + 1)
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(str2);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average of the numbers you entered is: " );
        }
    }

    public static double average(double[] array){
        double sum; 

        sum += array[i];
        double average = sum / array.length;

        return average;
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to call this in the main method and how to get the correct calculation. What is the best way to do this?  Do I need a for loop in the average method or should I keep it in the main?

Comment: can't average 0 numbers.  just a way to make sure the program runs without input errors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes you need a loop, try to do something like this:

```
public static double average(double[] array) {

    if(array.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    double average = sum / array.length;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: and the for loop in the main method as well, correct?

Comment: This will cause an error if the given array is of size 0.

Comment: I have it set up in the main method for this not to happen, i think.

Comment: @user3455588, sorry i didn't get what you mean?

Comment: @ifLoop i edited my answer, you people need any silly mistake to down-vote!!

Comment: I was referring to the comment above mine about the array being size 0...how would i call this average result in main?

Comment: In you code, the array size can't be 0, because you have an validation on the size not to be less than 1, and how to call it, after filling the numbers array just call the method like: `double avg = average(numbers);`, then print `avg` but out of the filling loop

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
StatUtils.mean(array);
```

you can find more about `StatUtils` [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/StatUtils.html#mean%28double%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 one might use Streams:

```
final double avg = array.length > 0 ? DoubleStream.of(array).sum() / array.length : 0;
```

Or in an own function:

```
public static double average(final double[] array) {
    return array.length > 0 ? DoubleStream.of(array).sum() / array.length : 0;
}
```